# Virtual Box Linux data recovery using R - Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery

I'm facing with the following problem. I have an Ubuntu virtual machine running with virtual box and I've accidently deleted some files from ubuntu .

I've googled for some tools that can aid me in recovering my lost data and came across [R-Linux](http://www.r-tt.com/data_recovery_linux/) which seems fit for the job, unfortunately R-linux runs from an windows host. My question is ,is there a way to run R-linux for my ubuntu virtual os

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about system files, and you did the smart thing and created a separate /home partition, you can just reinstall without worries. If not, you can backup the /home folder to a different virtual drive.

If you're talking about actual documents or videos in the home folder, check out this [Ubuntu Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Extract%20individual%20files%20from%20recovered%20image).

Comment: I need to recover a git repository

Comment: I don't have much experience in git, but I'm guessing that's it's no more than a folder. The guide above should work.